# How can i get server_id in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I am referring this document. I require server_id for uuid short function of mysql.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_server_id

How can i print server_id through mysql console?
Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
SELECT @@server_id
```

as `@@` points to global-defined variables (not like single `@` which is for session-defined variables)

For example,

```
SELECT CONCAT(@@server_id, UUID());
```

Answer (score 13):

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'server_id';

+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| server_id     | 1     |
+---------------+-------+

1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```